# Login fails after changing password ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0 and the identity stuff to authenticate and authorize the users. It all works fine except one single thing:

If the user resets or changes his password, he can't sign-in with the new credentials until the ASP.NET App is restarted. Means the new passwords are successfully saved in the database, but the Method `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` doesn't use the current data, but old one.  It seems there is something like a cache in the EF Core or in the SignInManager/UserStore.

Sign-in after registration works also fine, it is just a problem after reset or change of the passwords.

Comment: Are you using the redis or some in-process memory cache or so?

Comment: Nope, currently there is no cache configured. Just the default settings, nothing special.

Answer (score 4):

I too discovered a problem with my authentication middleware using a stale DbContext.

One solution was to refresh the user in the auth middleware's identity resolver with the following line of code:

`await _dbContext.Entry(userToVerify).ReloadAsync();`

Following this, I was able to verify the user's credentials against up-to-date data.

Answer (score 3):

Found the cause of that problem: 
Auth is done in a separate MiddleWare which has a wrong initialization and uses an old EF DbContext.

Using the DbContext with DI is a huge problem in ASP.NET Core. The DbContext should be used in a pretty small scope, defined with a simple using statement. Unfortunately the ASP.NET Core identity uses a DbContext which is registered in the DI. The better solution would be to register just a DbContext factory to the DI, to create a small scoped DbContext overtime you need it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight, I could see this tripping someone up for hours.

Comment: The insight is good, but not so much for dummies like me. I don't know how to properly register a DbContext factory, so I end up with a using (new DbContext) everywhere instead.